# Add alert below previous alert with position absolute?

Tags: javascript

I want to display alerts, and if one already exists, display the new one under that one. And so on.

This is what I'm doing right now, which doesn't exactly work as I want it to as it only works for 2 alerts or less shown at the same time.

```
var alert = document.createElement("div");

alert.className = "alert alert-" + type + " alert-dismissable";
alert.innerHTML = msg;

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(alert);

var currentAlerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");
if(currentAlerts.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= currentAlerts.length; i++) {
        if(currentAlerts[i] != undefined) {
            alert.style.top += ((i * 1.5) * currentAlerts[i].offsetHeight) + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the next alert be positioned right below the previous one with a spacing between them of 10 px?

Comment: Rest of the HTML ?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Where does type and msg come from ? What are the other alerts from currentAlerts, from where do you get them ? Give us a little more information about your HTML and JavaScript.